# How to send data from server to Android?

Tags: android, client-server, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project where I want my server to send some data to my application (without calling of web service from mobile). It is like a web panel which operates mobile app to add data. So when user add data in website and click add, it should add that data to the mobile app (if mobile is connected to the internet). It is also like sending command to android app.
I planned to use Push Notification (GCM) for this, but push notifications will not be a good option as I dnt want user to know that we are adding data in mobile app. It should add even if the app is not in active state or opened.

I think I have below 3 options

1. Make session between server and mobile. Start client server communication
2. Use SMS to send command then call web service as per the requirement
3. call web service after every 15-20 seconds to check for any update. (Even in Background)

Please advice if I have any other option to achieve this.

Comment: Without `web-service` and without `GCM` how can it possible?? If you dont want to used `web service` then remove 2nd  and 3rd options.

Comment: I have mentioned 2nd and 3rd option to just make others aware that these options which we have in total. I am looking for an option where I dnt have to use web service. But if nothing is available then definitely think for it to use in most efficient manner.

Comment: As per my aspect the only way is running a service in background that will update fetch data from your server and sync it. I have done this thing in my many apps. and as per your requirement `GCM` is not useful option here.

Comment: Ok Thanks @MD . Could you please advice if I have to run a background android service for this then should that android service call a web service just to check if any update is there or not? Same as option 3 but in background service only. 
Also how do you find option 2. Means sending an SMS to the user which the listener will detect and then perform accordingly. Listener will also delete that SMS from user's device immediately so that user will not   be get notified of it.

Comment: @sanchitsigh Ya off course. What you have to do is just call one main web service that'll check the `Date` is change into the server. If yes then some body touch your server(data) and if not then nothing to do.

Comment: @MD Thanks for your help. Do you think if I have any other option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74080/discussion-between-m-d-and-sanchitsingh).

Comment: 2 options, GCM for simple messages. For chat, Use XMPP. that will send message to app like chat application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really don't know where you're getting your information from, but both you and `MD` are wrong and GCM is the best option.

from your question:

> I planned to use Push Notification (GCM) for this, but push
>   notifications will not be a good option as I didn't want the user to know
>   that we are adding data in mobile app.

GCM is related to showing notifications to the user, but it's not what it does.

GCM is "Google Cloud Messaging". It  only sends a message to your app. This message is received inside a `BroadcastReceiver`. From inside this `BroadcastReceiver` you can execute any actions you need, like syncing the information with your server.

I'll show a possible example implementation of the `BroadcastReceiver` for the GCM.

That's a simplified example and NOT a complete implementation:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras(); // you send those extras from your server
        int type = b.getInt("type");
        switch(type){
            case TYPE_SYNC:
                 // start a `Service` to sync data from your server 
            break;
            case TYPE_ADD_DATA:
                 long id = b.getLong("id");
                 String name = b.getString("name");
                 String descr = b.getString("descr");
                 // call code to add id, name, descr to your local data
            break;
            case TYPE_NOTIFICATION:
                 String title = b.getString("title");
                 String message = b.getString("message");
                 // call code to make a notification with title and message
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

on this example your server can send 3 different types of GCM.

- TYPE_SYNC: will make your app start a background service that will connect to the server and sync information
- TYPE_ADD_DATA: will send the data directly inside the message and that gets directly added to the device storage (SQLite probably)
- TYPE_NOTIFICATION: this is the only option that the user gets notified about anything. The other two options are transparent for the user.

for a complete implementation and how to properly use the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` please check the official docs: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: You answer is quite explanatory, but don't you feel that GCM have a low success rate for such data in real time. How will you handle it.