# How send the http post request with DataOutPutStream properly so server can handle it

Tags: java, python, android

> ## I wish somebody tell me what is the different of just write a file and a file with another kind of bytes.

server using, python3 flask

I think maybe the android retrofit etc useful, but I would like to try with the classic method, HTTPUrlConnection
So i successfully sending just one or multi-parameter of string to the server.
I also successfully just by sending a file to the server.
- my file will just 5-second audio or video mp4 that creates from real android.

When i tried just two, param and a list of byte, len(list) = 2, i can get back my sent file, but the concat style of the bytes just could not acheive it.

but when I combine both of it, i found out that when the file is chopped as multi-part, the file just could not recover.

### I know delimeter is useful, I tried with a string of "--------------" to split it in server-side.

```
list= request.data.split(b"------------------------------")
newList= list[1:]
data = b""
for part in newList:
    data += part
```

### how i recover the file (python)

```
def createAudioFromDataReceived(fileName, data):
with open(fileName, 'wb') as wfile:
    wfile.write(data)
```

### the basic code write to dataOutPutStream

```
public void writeFilesParamToDataOutputStream(HttpURLConnection conn, File file, String action) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

    int length = 0;
    while ( ( length = fileInputStream.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    dos.flush();
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.close();
}
```

### to add extra line to the dataOutputStream

```
//Bytes
byte[] bytes = "toSend".getBytes();
dos.write(bytes);
dos.write("------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

ops, reference are seen before 
roughly this kind [How to send data from server to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340596/how-to-send-data-from-server-to-android)

i could not imagine the byte got alot of "-" and need "/r/n" ...

delimiter should be some thing like

```
String delimiter = "--aaWEdFXvDF--" + "\r\n";
```